# How to Delete files of some pattern using bash and commit using svn

Tags: svn, find, delete-file

I have a lot of .sql files in multiple folders.. it will be a hectic work to mention the path of it individually...

I am wondering is there and way I can use linux commands to delete those files and commit it using SVN.

the case is

folder1/a.sql

folder2/a/ad.sql

like wise some 25 files

I want to do something like `find -type f -iname "*.sql"` and `svn commit` the deleted files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `find . -name "*.sql" -exec svn delete '{}' \;`
2. `svn commit -m "My Log Message"`